# How to add the Wiring S board to Arduino IDE v.1.6.2?

Tags: arduino-uno, sketch, sketch-size

My Arduino Uno is running out of memory to support my script (yes, I've tried several ways of optimize it already: PROGMEM, EEPROM, no Strings, and so on), so I would like to upload my script to my [Wiring S](http://wiring.org.co/hardware/) board.

However, instead of "porting" all libraries to Wiring, I would like to compile my script in Arduino IDE and upload it to my Wiring S. It used to be "easy" in Arduino v.1.0.x. because somwhere I got a Wiring folder (containing, among other things, a boards.txt file) and copied it to Arduino's `hardware` folder getting the Wiring S board listed in Arduino IDE.

Since Arduino 1.5 the [specification for adding other boards changed](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5---3rd-party-Hardware-specification). I'd say it's more complex now. I simply cannot understand most of the new specification (yes, I'm new into electronics), so I haven't been able to add my Wiring S board.

Running my script in Arduino 1.0.x doesn't seem to be an option, since it throws lots of errors (although the script compiles in Arduino 1.6.2).

Do you have any experience adding other boards (like Wiring S) to Arduino IDE? Could you please give me some hint?

Comment: Which version? There seem to be 4 different chips on these boards. What is the main chip? PS new specification isn't that different. It requires everything to be put in an folder (`avr`), and requires a platform.txt file with just a name and version (two lines). The boards.txt file has some variables with new names. You'll get some error messages in the IDE is something is incorrect.

Comment: You're right, but those changes are enough for us basic users to be unable to work with the configuration we used to work with. On the other hand, it's Wiring S v.1.0, it looks exactly like this one: http://www.lextronic.fr/P22978-platine-de-developpement-wiring-s.html

Comment: The one you link to is a Atmega644P, while v1.0 is atmega128. What boards.txt file did you use for the Arduino 1.0? So I can try to port it for you.

Comment: I use Wiring S, that works with AtMega644p. The confusion arose because on top of the microcontroller, there is a sticker saying "WIRING S 1.0" (as shown in the link I posted). So, Wiring S, AtMega644p. The boards.txt I used is https://titanpad.com/wiringsboards Thanks!

Comment: [Here is my attempt at porting](http://algemeenbekend.nl/misc/WiringS.zip). I don't have that board, so I can't really test it. Just be careful, as the pin numbers might be different on the board, then in the IDE. Also check the higher number pins.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I do; I use the Serial.print(F("string/n")); which prints the data from flash rather then copying it to ram.  Keep as many of your variables local as possible, that will save ram.  This is done by defining then in the function, the added advantage nothing outside the function can change them.

Global and Static variables are the first things loaded into SRAM. They push the start of the heap upward toward the stack and they will occupy this space for all eternity.

Variables created in functions, are dynamically allocated objects and data. Unlike Global and Static variables, these variables can be de-allocated to free up space at function exit. But Every function call creates a stack frame that makes the stack grow toward the heap. This data is usable within the function, but the space is 100% reclaimed when the function exits!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I'm not really asking for hints on saving program space.